# How can I sort an object by key value?

Tags: flutter

I have this data and I want to sort all the `type_description` value ascending. How can I do this?

```
data = [
  {
    'name': 'asd',
    'contact': [{
        "country_code": "1",
        "area_code": null,
        "contact_no": "4616984351",
        "email": null,
        "type_description": "Mobile - Primary"
      },
      {
        "country_code": null,
        "area_code": "416",
        "contact_no": "6984351",
        "email": null,
        "type_description": "Landline - Business"
      },
      {
        "country_code": null,
        "area_code": null,
        "contact_no": null,
        "email": "n81ikrfepi@temporary-mail.net",
        "type_description": "Email - Primary"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'dsa',
    'contact': [{
        "country_code": "1",
        "area_code": null,
        "contact_no": "4616984351",
        "email": null,
        "type_description": "Mobile - Primary"
      },
      {
        "country_code": null,
        "area_code": "416",
        "contact_no": "6984351",
        "email": null,
        "type_description": "Landline - Business"
      },
      {
        "country_code": null,
        "area_code": null,
        "contact_no": null,
        "email": "n81ikrfepi@temporary-mail.net",
        "type_description": "Email - Primary"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I'm expecting the data to be look like this

```
data = [
  {
    'name': 'asd',
    'contact': [{
        "country_code": null,
        "area_code": null,
        "contact_no": null,
        "email": "n81ikrfepi@temporary-mail.net",
        "type_description": "Email - Primary"
      },
      {
        "country_code": null,
        "area_code": "416",
        "contact_no": "6984351",
        "email": null,
        "type_description": "Landline - Business"
      },
      {
        "country_code": "1",
        "area_code": null,
        "contact_no": "4616984351",
        "email": null,
        "type_description": "Mobile - Primary"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'dsa',
    'contact': [{
        "country_code": null,
        "area_code": null,
        "contact_no": null,
        "email": "n81ikrfepi@temporary-mail.net",
        "type_description": "Email - Primary"
      },
      {
        "country_code": null,
        "area_code": "416",
        "contact_no": "6984351",
        "email": null,
        "type_description": "Landline - Business"
      },
      {
        "country_code": "1",
        "area_code": null,
        "contact_no": "4616984351",
        "email": null,
        "type_description": "Mobile - Primary"
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

do insert the jsondata in the variable name datastore

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> dataStrore = [put all json data here];
```

Now do the sort

```
dataStore.forEach((user){
List<Map<String, dynamic>> contact = user['contact'];
contact.sort((a,b)) => a['type_discription'].compareTo(b['typediscription'])));
})
```

Now print and see the sorted data

```
print(dataStore)
```